# CI_Merchant is not displaying anything

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, ci-merchant

For an online payment, I am trying to use ci_merchant. According to http://ci-merchant.org/
, I made a CodeIgniter project. But the function is displaying only blank page.

My function is given below:

```
 function transaction(){
    $this->load->library('merchant');
    $this->merchant->load('paypal_express');
    $settings = $this->merchant->default_settings();

    $settings = array(
        'username' => 'AAAAAAAAAAA',
        'password' => '111111',
        'signature' => 'AAAAAAAAAAAARCpSSRl31AoJ0SIOUHEnDbhhEgANdZeAmMTkU',
        'test_mode' => true
    );
    $this->merchant->initialize($settings);

        $params = array(
            'amount' => 1.00,
            'currency' => 'USD',
            'return_url' => 'http://localhost/tcm/account/transaction_return',
            'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost/tcm/account/transaction_cancel'
        );
        //'return_url' => 'https://www.example.com/checkout/payment_return/123',
        //'cancel_url' => 'https://www.example.com/checkout');
        $response = $this->merchant->purchase($params);

        if ($response->success()){
            echo "Successfully complete transaction.";
        }
        else{
            $message = $response->message();
            echo('Error processing payment: ' . $message);
            exit;
        } 
}
```

Where is the problem of my code or procedure ? Awaiting for an affirmative response.

Comment: try adding something like `echo "this point achieved";` at the top to make sure this function was executeed

Comment: I checked that, the function is working.

Comment: try `echo $this->merchant->purchase($params)->success();` and `echo $this->merchant->purchase($params)->message();` before your if statement

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the `$this->` part in below code snippet:

```
if ($response->success()){
            echo "Successfully complete transaction.";
        }
        else{
            $message = $response->message();
            echo('Error processing payment: ' . $message);
            exit;
        }
```

try it with:

```
if ($response->$this->success()){
            echo "Successfully complete transaction.";
        }
        else{
            $message = $response->$this->message();
            echo('Error processing payment: ' . $message);
            exit;
        }
```

Comment: Same problem no output.